# ReactJS & Redux - TypeError: state.reduxCart is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-reducers

I am trying to insert items in redux but when i click the button I get the following error :

```
TypeError: state.reduxCart is not iterable
```

My Reducer code :

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    reduxCart: [],
    reduxCartCounter: 0
}


export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case 'ADDITEM':
            return {
                ...state,
                reduxCart: [action.payload , ...state.reduxCart]  // ERROR
            }

        case 'ADDCOUNTER':
            return ({
                ...state,
                reduxCartCounter: action.payload
            })

        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

Here is my Store code :

```
import rootReducer from './reducer';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'; 

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
}


const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
const persistor = persistStore(store);
export { store, persistor };
```

My Actions Code :

```
export function AddToReduxCart(item) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: 'ADDITEM', payload: item  })
    }
}
```

How to solve this issue ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your store creation code?

Comment: Shared it above.

Comment: Can you console.log your initial state to see if you have a presistent redux store without the cart? Right after `createStore`

Comment: Yes i have persistent redux store.

Comment: Yes I can see that ;) Can you console.log your state after that?

Comment: `const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk)); console.log(store)`, press F12 and click on Console to see it.

Comment: i got this in my console :

    {dispatch: ƒ, subscribe: ƒ, getState: ƒ, replaceReducer: ƒ, Symbol(observable): ƒ}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225196/discussion-between-niko-bellic-and-domino987).

Answer (score 1):

On your actions file, in your addItem function you can use getState function. then concat the two of the arrays in your action and dispatch them as the payload.

should be something like this:

```
import store from '../store';

export function addItem(nextItem) {
  const currentReduxCart = store.getState().reduxCart.map(item => ({...item}));
  const payload = [nextItem , ...currentReduxCart];
  return {
    type: 'ADDITEM',
    payload: payload,
  }
}
```

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    reduxCart: [],
    reduxCartCounter: 0
}


export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case 'ADDITEM':
            return {
                ...state,
                reduxCart: action.payload
            }

        case 'ADDCOUNTER':
            return ({
                ...state,
                reduxCartCounter: action.payload
            })

        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

If you want to add your actions code I will be able to help You to adjust it for your code.

Comment: I added it above.

Comment: The code works fine if I don't add redux-persist in my store. After adding redux-persist I get a TypeError that state is not iterateable. Is there any way to get it working with the redux-persist ?

Comment: Can you console.log the state.reduxCart before it throws an error, and post it here?

Comment: I updated the code, can you try it now? if it is still not working, can you please send me an example for an item in the redux cart and console.log currentReduxCart